# Before delete trigger on SQL.

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I was trying to create a before `delete` trigger so, in case the user put an incorrect `id`, he would get an error message.
I used the following code...

```
CREATE TRIGGER pos_id
BEFORE DELETE ON CLIENTS 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

DECLARE TOTAL INT;
SET TOTAL = ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM CLIENTS ) ;

IF( old.id <0 OR old.id > total ) 
  THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error. Client doesn't exist';

END IF ;
END
```

Besides, it doesn't work. The message doesn't appear, and the trigger doesn't seem to work. While I was searching to find a solution to my problem on the Internet, I learnt about instead of triggers, which I found really interesting.

But when I try...

```
 CREATE TRIGGER pos_id
    INSTEAD OF DELETE ON CLIENTS 
    BEGIN
(...)
```

or...

```
CREATE TRIGGER pos_id
ON CLIENTS 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
BEGIN
(...)
```

I get a `syntax error`. So I really have 2 questions:

1º Why my before delete trigger doesn't work? Am I really missing something?
2º What's the syntax error related to instead of delete trigger?

Thank you so much.

Comment: PhPMyAdmin. I realized I made a big mistake with ''IF( old.id <0 OR old.id > total ) '' because if I removed clients, there could be a client with id=4, but count(*) would return a minor number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with a trigger. The trigger will only fire for a delete that matches at least one row, so if a user tries to delete a non-existent client rather than getting your custom error they will just get this:

```
mysql > delete from clients where id = -1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Furthermore, you should explicitly check for the existence of the row rather than relying on whether the input is less than zero or greater than the row count in the table, etc. Also you need to escape the apostrophe in your error message.

You can accomplish this with a stored procedure. If you can get users to delete rows using your stored procedure rather than executing explicit deletes against the client table then you can throw your custom error.

For example (I don't know the data type of the id column. I assumed int, but you should change it to match the actual data type in your table):

```
delimiter $$

drop procedure if exists delete_client $$

create procedure delete_client (p_client_id int) 
begin
  declare v_client_exists int default 0;

  select count(*)
  into v_client_exists
  from clients 
  where id = p_client_id;

   if (v_client_exists = 0)
   then
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error. Client doesn''t exist';
   else
     delete from clients where id = p_client_id;
   end if;

end $$

delimiter ;
```

Then do the delete like this:

```
mysql > call delete_client(-1);
ERROR 1644 (45000): Error. Client doesn't exist
mysql > call delete_client(2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql > call delete_client(2);
ERROR 1644 (45000): Error. Client doesn't exist
```

Comment: Also, the `old.id` in the trigger is the existing value on the table, not the value you are trying to use.  Plus to add to @Ike's comment about _"whether the input is ... greater than the row count in the table"_ This is bad coding in a second way, because if rows are deleted, the `count(*)` <> the `max(id)`.